# Why can't I remove the {0, 0} in Circle[{0, 0}] using pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching

Why does

```
Circle[{0, 0}] /. List[_?NumericQ ..] :> Sequence[]
```

return

> Circle[{0, 0}]

yet

```
Circle[{0, 0}] /. List[_?NumericQ ..] :> List
```

returns

> Circle[List]

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the definition of `Circle[]` is `Circle[{0, 0}]`. As soon as `{0, 0}` is replaced by `Sequence[]`, this definition kicks in, thus rendering the replacement useless.